# Classify words to "good" and "bad"

Tags: python, algorithm, scala, classification, text-mining

I have a list of domain names and want to determine is name of domain looks like it is porno site or not. What the better way to do this? List of porn domains looks like http://dumpz.org/56957/ . This domains can be used to teach the system how porno domains should look like. Also I have other list - http://dumpz.org/56960/ - many domains of this list also is porno and I want to determine them by name.

Comment: Umm, on an unrelated note, how did arstechnica.com end up on that list...?

Comment: @martin-tornwall: http://dumpz.org/56963/

Comment: Specially if you are doing it as intellectual exercise, you can check out Python's [nltk library](http://www.nltk.org).  The classifiers are explained in [nltk documentation](http://www.opendocs.net/nltk/0.9.5/guides/classify.html).  Do note that your training data should include some negative domains as well (i.e. domains that are not porn domains).

Comment: @notnoop: Thanks, will look to this library. What about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier ? Can it be used for this task?

Comment: @Mykola, you can use any classifier, including Naive Bayes classifier, which is included in the nltk library.  Good results depend on the classifier you choose and the quality of the features.  That being said, maybe domain name analysis may not be the best heuristic.

Comment: Ars Technica is a good example of why this approach is broken. Just because some porn-like search terms show up the domain doesn't mean that everything (or even a substantial fraction) hosted on the domain is porn.

Comment: @Nick, search for porno site in google only one of many other approaches I plan to use. Other criteria is: score for domain name,  score for content at site, score of domain ip(virtual hosting), score of nameservers which is used for domains, etc.

Comment: @Mykola My point is about classifying by domain, not about how you score them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a bayesian filter eg: [SpamBayes](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/) or Divmods Reverend. You train it with the list you have and could score how likely it is for a given domain, if it is porn.

For a short overview look at [this](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/244.html) article.

Answer (score 5):

You can't rely on the domain name for that, there are far too many porn domains with decent names and few others with porn-like names but with safe content.

Comment: Yes, sure, but domain name can be one of many other criteria. As you can see from two lists - there is some correlation.

Comment: For now I have database of 10k potentially porno domains. This week I will try approach to classify domain names and will publish results.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on what your goals are.  I'm guessing that you are mostly interested in minimizing false negatives (accidentally calling a domain a good domain if it isn't).  This might be true if, for example, you want all porn links in a forum to be reviewed for spam before being posted.  If some non-porn links get flagged for review, it's OK.

In this case, you could probably do something fairly simple.  If you could come up with a list of porn'ish words, you could just mark all of the domains that contain any of those words as a substring.  This would catch some safe domains though: expertsexchange.com could match "sex" or "sexchange", but "yahoo" wouldn't ever flag positive.  Easy to implement, easy to understand, easy to tweak.

Lists of obscene words can be found using your favorite search engine.  You could use your list of domains to extract common long substrings across the domains as words as well.

If you want to really get the answers correct though, you'll need to see what is on those domains.  Site-About-Kitty-Porn.com could be a lolcats domain or illegal porn.  Impossible to know unless you do some crawling.  If you fetch the actual content and matched against your list, you'd be doing a little better.

You could also try each domain against some third party service, such as a child-safe internet filter, or even trying to test if the domain will appear for safe-search results in your favorite search engine.  Of course, make sure you are following each service's TOS and all of that.

Answer (score 1):

As someone already pointed out, you need some kind of classification to achieve what you are trying to. But then overall accuracy (precision and recall) depends on the training dataset you have. You could use classifiers like SVM, decision tree, etc. for this purpose.

I would suggest to go for a semi-supervised approach where you cluster your different URLs and check a few representative URLs from each cluster to see if that is porn or not. The benefit is you don need any training and you can find porn URLs which probably do not cover your training dataset. The common clustering techniques are k-means, hierarchical, dbscan, etc.
This will still not cover porn sites which do not have porn like URL. For that you have to grab the page and need to do similar training/clustering on the content of the webpage(s).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
scala> val pornList = List("porn1.com","porn2.com","porn3.com")
pornList: List[java.lang.String] = List(porn1.com, porn2.com, porn3.com)

scala> val sites = List("porn1.com","site1.com","porn3.com","site2.com","site3.com")
sites: List[java.lang.String] = List(porn1.com, site1.com, porn3.com, site2.com, site3.com)

scala> val result = sites filterNot { pornList contains _ }
result: List[java.lang.String] = List(site1.com, site2.com, site3.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post on [classifying webpages by topic](http://www.etherealbits.com/?p=106).  Start with the list of bad sites as your positive examples and use any heuristic for finding good sites (basic web crawler seeded with some innocent Google searches) as negative examples.  The post walks you through the process of extracting content through the pages and touches on Weka and how you might apply some of their basic learners.

Note that you may want to add additional data to your training set that is specific to the domain of your problem instead of just using page contents.  For example the number of pictures or size of pictures on the page may be a factor that you may want to consider.